# Assistance with using loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Basically I'm trying to create a function in which it takes parameters, the times table required, and the values at which it should start and end. The function is to return a formatted string that can be displayed in the output area. 
The rest of the code will get the three values from the textboxes and call the multiplication table function.
The return value will be displayed in a text area.
An example of what it should look like:

[image: Example output]

My JS currently looks like this:

```
function btnDisplay_onclick()
{
    // get textboxes and assign to variables
    var tableTextbox = document.getElementById("txtTable");
    var startTextbox = document.getElementById("txtStart");
    var finishTextbox = document.getElementById("txtFinish");
    var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtOutput");

    var table = tableTextbox.value;
    var start = startTextbox.value;
    var finish = finishTextbox.value;

    var output = multiply(table, start, finish);

    outputTextbox.value = output;

}

function multiply(table, start, finish)
{
    for

}
```

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <title>Multiplication Table</title>
    <script src="Lab6-MultTable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action=#>
        <p><h1>Multiplication Table</h1></p>
        <p>
            Table Number:<input type="text" id="txtTable"><br>
            Start Number:<input type="text" id="txtStart"><br>
            Finish Number:<input type="text" id="txtFinish"><br>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea id="txtOutput" rows="8" cols="20" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Display Numbers" id="btnDisplay" onclick="btnDisplay_onclick()">
            <input type="reset">
        </p>
    </form>
    <noscript>This website requires JavaScript to be enabled.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically I'm having trouble learning how to use Loops properly if someone would be willing to explain it to me as reading up on it I'm not able to fully understand it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the processing of the value a bit, like

```
var table = +tableTextbox.value || 0;
```

That converts the value to number and checks for a truthy value. If falsy, take zero as value.

For multiplication take the start and end value for the for loop and a variable for the result.

Calculate the value and add the line to the result, return the result.

```
function multiply(table, start, finish) {
    var i, result = '';
    for (i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
        result += table + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + table * i + '\n';
    }
    return result;
}
```

```js
function btnDisplay_onclick()  {
    // get textboxes and assign to variables
    var tableTextbox = document.getElementById("txtTable");
    var startTextbox = document.getElementById("txtStart");
    var finishTextbox = document.getElementById("txtFinish");
    var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtOutput");

    var table = +tableTextbox.value || 0;   // convert to number and
    var start = +startTextbox.value || 0;   // testfor truthynes or take 
    var finish = +finishTextbox.value || 0; // the default value of 0

    var output = multiply(table, start, finish);

    outputTextbox.value = output;

}

function multiply(table, start, finish) {
    var i, result = '';
    for (i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
        result += table + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + table * i + '\n';
    }
    return result;
}
```

```html
    <form action="">
        <p><h1>Multiplication Table</h1></p>
        <p>
            Table Number:<input type="text" id="txtTable"><br>
            Start Number:<input type="text" id="txtStart"><br>
            Finish Number:<input type="text" id="txtFinish"><br>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea id="txtOutput" rows="8" cols="20" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Display Numbers" id="btnDisplay" onclick="btnDisplay_onclick()">
            <input type="reset">
        </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it? I've never done  var table = +tableTextbox.value || 0;   // convert to number and
before is there a more basic/ beginner way of doing things?

Comment: that is the beginner way ... i mean, you could use the string and use the implicit typecasting of the multiplication, but i think, you like to use something like [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). but that does not prevent you to check for [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), because of not inserted values. (you may just check above and submit without values)

Comment: I just attempted to remove the =+ and || 0; and put     var table = tableTextbox.value; and it still works why was the other bit needed?

Comment: as i wrote, the implicit typecasting of the multiplication convertes strings to number. for example `alert('3' * '4');'` returns 12. that is because the operator `*` requires two numbers and tries to cast the operands to number. but it may fail, if you take a string with some letters. then you get `NaN`, Not a Number as result.

Comment: Thank you, but just 2 last questions. Firstly what exactly does the = +tableTextbox.value mean (like the actual + what does that do)? and also I'm new to this pretty much and im not well versed with what all the commands and functions may be += in the loop what does that mean as well.

Comment: the pattern `= +` means an assignment with an [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), which first converts the following expression to number. please see link. the pattern without space [`+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) is an addition assignment, which adds the right part to the left variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is write the result inside the loop at `textarea`.

```js
$("#display").on("click", function(){
   multiply();         
});                

function multiply(){
  var table = document.getElementById("table").value
    , start = document.getElementById("start").value
    , finish = document.getElementById("finish").value
    , text = document.getElementById("result");
  text.value = '';
  for ( var i = start ; i <= finish ; i++ ){
      text.value +=  table + " * " + i + " = " + (table * i) + "\n";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="parameters">
    Table number: <input id="table" type="number" />
    <br/>
    Start number: <input id="start" type"number" />
    <br/>
    Finish number: <input id="finish" type"number" />
  <div>
  
  <textarea id="result" rows="8" cols="20" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
  </text>
  <br/><br/>
    
  <button id="display" /> Display numbers
  <button type="reset" /> Reset
</form>
```